# How to select distinct values from a column in Mapbasic?

Tags: sql, mapinfo, mapbasic

I have a table in a mapinfo .tab file. Is there any way to select distinct values from the column?

I tried :-

```
SELECT distinct (some_column) from table_name into temp_table
```

But this query would select all values. I wanted to select only distinct value from that column. Is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MapInfo Pro does not support the Distinct keywork, unfortunately. However you can get to the same result just be grouping your result by the column

```
Select some_column from table_name into temp_table Group By some_column
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears if you simply group by column name, the results only come up once ( as per a distinct)
Just tested in MapInfo 10.0

Comment: Welcome to our site! Could you perhaps provide an explicit example of what the command looks like and the output it would give for a simple dataset?